# How to change basepath on deployment of Vue app

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, github-pages, vue-cli

I have a Vue 2.0 webapplication that runs without problems on my computer, but I can't seem to get it to work on a server without the app running on the root directory.

e.g: '`www.someserver.com/my-app/`' instead of '`www.someserver.com/`'.

I used the [webpack-simple template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/) which has [this basic webpack configuration](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/blob/master/template/webpack.config.js). How can I make sure that the app will load the files from the folder instead of the root?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. So the assets aren't loading from the correct location when built. So you would want to modify the `publicPath` variable depending on `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Comment: I already tried something like that but I could not get it right. I am currently using [this webpack configuration](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/blob/master/template/webpack.config.js). Could you maybe have a look at it and maybe show me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I indeed had to edit the `publicPath` entry in my `webpack.config.js`, like so:

```js
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin("main.css")],
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

  module.exports.output.publicPath = '/<REPO_NAME>/dist/';

  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map';
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    /*new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),*/
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Mind the `<REPO_NAME> publicPath` entry in the `production` part.

Next, I also had to update the links in my `index.html` to use the dot-notation instead of just regular relative paths:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>listz-app</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="./dist/build.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This configuration works to deploy `Vue-cli 2.0` webapplication to [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

Answer (score 15):

On file `vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  /* ... */
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/my-app/' : '/'
}
```

On file `router.js`

```js
/* ... */
import { publicPath } from '../vue.config'
/* ... */
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: publicPath,
    /* ... */
})
```

Comment: if you're using vite, publicPath is called "base" in vite.config.js. Not sure how to import the config from vite.config.js because it's defined as a function.

Comment: The change on [vue.config] was enough for me to fix the error. I was missing a "/" before "my-app". I didn't use the change on [router] though. Setting "base : publicPath" was causing the build to be unable to find the build files.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your server is already serving your html/js bundles when you go to the url you want....  If you are using vue-router, you also need to set the base path there.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  base: "/my-app/",
  routes
})
```

Comment: Then the problem could be that your server is not configured to serve your page at that url.  Have you checked your IIS or Express configuration?  You should edit your question to show the error you are getting.

Comment: This is for deployment to [github-pages](https://pages.github.com/), so I can't edit or see the settings of the webserver.

Comment: thanks Leo Bartkus

Answer (score 6):

In VUE 3 with vite:

Inside vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue({
            reactivityTransform: true
        })
    ],

    base: '/myNewFolder/',
})
```

More info : https://vitejs.dev/config/#base

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching for 30 minutes about why "publicPath" wasn't working, but it was because Vue was bundled with Vite.

Comment: base: '/myNewFolder/', line in vite.config.js helped solve my problem also. Now the js and css files path starts with ./assets/.... I didnt need vue.config.js

Answer (score 2):

This has recently been a problem for me. And the above solutions did not work.

The below solution works for `vue 2.6`, and `vue-router 3.1`

What I did was to add a relative path as as suggested [in this git issue](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/publicpath-in-production/79698) in `vue.config.js`:

```
  module.exports = {
      publicPath: './',
      // Your config here
  }
```

But this did not the entire solution since router views were not rendered, making it necessary to add a base path in the router. The base path must be the same as the `vue.config.js's publicPath`, to do so use `location.pathname`, as suggested [in this forum question](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/issues/312).
The complete solution in `router.js` is:

```
mode: 'history',
base: location.pathname,
routes: [
  // Your routes here
]
```